# SnappyData Job API

Tags: snappydata

We have created a job by extending SnappySqlJob and overriding runSnappyJob and isValidJob.

In runSnappyJob we are creating connection to Kafka to poll messages from Kafka in every 1 second.

After terminating the job using:

```
bin/snappy-job.sh stop  --lead lead:8090 --job-id <job_id>
```

we can see in the logs that Kafka is still polling the data.

Is there any API to check the status of running job so that we can stop the Kafka consumer?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about this behavior you noticed but you should use a SnappyStreamingJob instead of SnappyJob for managing streaming jobs.
See https://snappydatainc.github.io/snappydata/programming_guide/snappydata_jobs/ ... there is a link to the examples from there.